# How to exclude certain dependencies from being added to the Class-Path in maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I'm using `maven` to build an executable `JAR` and I want to add all dependencies minus a select few to the `Class-Path` of my `MANIFEST.MF`. So far I'm using the `maven-jar-plugin` for this:

```
<!-- Add dependent JARs to the classpath -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libraries</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works for adding all dependencies. However, I furthermore want to exclude certain dependencies from being added to the `Class-Path`. According to [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) you can use the `exclude` tag as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**selenium*</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

I would expect this to exclude any dependency which has `selenium` in the name but it does not work. For example I would like to exclude `libraries/selenium-json-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar` from the `Class-Path`. Even if I specify that exact name it does not exclude anything. I would also like to provide the `groupId` for exclusion similar to how the `maven-dependency-plugin`'s `excludeGroupIds` tag works.

How can the desired `Class-Path` management be done using `maven`?

I'm also using `maven-shade-plugin` for building the executable (fat) `JAR` but its manifest manipulation facilities seem lesser known/documented. Setting the `Class-Path` using `maven-shade-plugin` via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17891813/3764804) answer works but how can I populate my dependencies with exclusions instead of hard-coding everything?

Comment: Have you already found a solution to this? If so, please update.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

The `includes` and `excludes` parameters of the Maven JAR Plugin work on **files**, not on **dependencies**.

### Longer version

Selenium is typically used as a test dependency. Is Selenium declared as a Maven dependency? If it's only used for tests, I would expect it to have `<scope>test</scope>`. In that case, it will not end up in the JAR manifest.

If you don't use Selenium as a test dependency and still don't want it to end up in the manifest, you may consider adding `<scope>provided</scope>`. Provided dependencies don't end up in the JAR manifest either. This would also mean that at runtime, as soon as you invoke a Selenium API it will probably crash...

Comment: Actually, sorry for undoing the accepted answer but I realized that using the `provided` scope also excludes the dependency's classes etc. from being included in the `JAR` and not only the `Class-Path` entries. I want to include the classes etc. but not generate a `Class-Path` entry since the code is already present in the `JAR` and does not need to be referenced externally via the `Class-Path`. You see, I want some dependencies to be merged into the `JAR` and other external dependencies referenced via the `Class-Path`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're shading all dependencies into one JAR file? I guess in that case, you shouldn't need to configure set `addClasspath` or `classpathPrefix` for the Maven JAR plugin, since the JAR would contain all dependencies needed.

Comment: No. I'm shading some dependencies into the `JAR` and I'm copying most others into a `libraries` folder so that the main `JAR` can reference them from the `Class-Path`. The latter part should exclude the dependencies which I'm already shading into the `JAR`.

Comment: OK, I understand what you want, although I don't understand _why_. But that's less important. Unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve what you want. As to my knowledge, it's a bit uncommon, though.

Comment: I'm doing this for obfuscation and convenience purposes. I want my local maven libraries to be shaded into the `JAR` so I can obfuscate the main JAR and keep the library `JAR`s untouched since they're open source anyway. This way I can reduce the size of the main `JAR` and obfuscation would take much longer when applied to every single dependency and my code at the same time.