# Replacing the MANIFEST.MF file in a JAR programmatically

Tags: java, jar, zip, manifest.mf, zip4j

I want to modify the `MANIFEST.MF` after creating the `JAR` to [exclude certain `Class-Path` entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173831). For this I decided to use [`zip4j`](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j). Extraction seems to work fine but for putting the `MANIFEST.MF` file back into the `JAR`, I use the following code:

```
String metaInfFolderName = "META-INF";
Path extractedManifestFilePath = Paths.get("...");
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("Test-Zip-File.zip");
ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
zipParameters.setDefaultFolderPath(metaInfFolderName);
zipFile.addFile(extractedManifestFilePath.toFile(), zipParameters);
```

However, this code does not work as expected: The parent directory always ends up being named `NF` instead of the full `META-INF`. It seems like the starting characters are cut off. What could be the reason for this or is there another meaningful possibility to replace files inside `JAR`s (which are essentially just `ZIP`s)?

`maven` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore I tried using the `jar` utility like described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html) but when invoking the command `jar uf MyJAR.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` the `MANIFEST.MF` inside the `JAR` gets deleted instead of replaced. Using the `zip` utility via `zip -ur MyJAR.jar "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"` works but corrupts the `JAR` file so it is no longer runnable:

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file MyJAR.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class ManifestManipulator {

    public static final void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("at least the path to the JAR file expected!");
        }
        Path jarPath = Paths.get(args[0]);
        Set<String> attributeNames = args.length > 1 ? new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(args).subList(1, args.length)) : Set.of();

        if (!attributeNames.isEmpty()) {
            ManifestManipulator manifestManipulator = new ManifestManipulator();
            manifestManipulator.removeManifestEntries(jarPath, attributeNames);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Warning: no entries specified to remove!");
        }
    }

    private void removeManifestEntries(Path jarPath, Set<String> attributeNames) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Going to remove: " + attributeNames);
        try (FileSystem jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + jarPath.toUri()), Map.of())) {
            Path manifestPath = jarFS.getPath("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF");
            Manifest manifest = readManifest(manifestPath);
            Attributes mainAttributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
            System.out.println("Found main attribute names: " + mainAttributes.keySet());

            boolean removed = mainAttributes.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> attributeNames.contains(((Name) entry.getKey()).toString()));
            if (removed) {
                writeManifest(manifestPath, manifest);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Warning: nothing removed");
            }
        }
    }

    private Manifest readManifest(Path manifestPath) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(manifestPath)) {
            return new Manifest(is);
        }
    }

    private void writeManifest(Path manifestPath, Manifest manifest) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(manifestPath)) {
            manifest.write(os);
        }
    }

}
```

Please make sure you've added the [jdk.zipfs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) module, which will provide a [FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) for ZIP/JAR files (see the [technote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)).

Comment: I'm actually still using `Java 8`, is your code or something similar still functional under that version? If not, it's also okay actually, I can certainly migrate to a newer Java version.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza It should also be working with Java 8 with some minor changes (replace List.of() with Arrays.asList() etc.). At least the Oracle JDK 8 has the ZIP/JAR FileSystemProvider already on the classpath out-of-the-box (so it's even simpler than with Java 11).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any external dependency to alter the content of a ZIP or JAR file with Java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path zipFilePath = Paths.get("path/to/my/app.jar");
    try (FileSystem zipFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null)) {
        Path manifestFile = zipFileSystem.getPath("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        String newManifestContent;
        // Read from MANIFEST.MF.
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(manifestFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            newManifestContent = lines.filter(l -> !l.startsWith("Class-Path entry I want to remove"))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
        // Replace MANIFEST.MF content.
        Files.write(manifestFile, newManifestContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```